# Typerror: 'vector' not callable

Tags: python, game-engine

I am tying to make a go-kart game in blender.
Im not even halfway completed but, my code doesnt seem to work.
please help.

this is the code:

```
import bge

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner

#var
maxvel = 0.5     #const
brkvel = 0.05   #const
crsvel = 0.005  #const
accell = 0.001  #const

#inputs
w = cont.sensors['W']
s = cont.sensors['S']
a = cont.sensors['A']
d = cont.sensors['D']
space = cont.sensors['space']

#outputs
motion =    cont.actuators['motion']

        ##movement

    #accelerate     
if w.positive:
    own['vel'] += accell
    motion.dLoc=([own['vel'],0.0,0.0])
    cont.activate(motion)

if space.positive and own['vel'] > 0 :
    own['vel'] -= brkvel
    motion.dLoc([own['vel'],0.0,0.0])
    cont.activate(motion)
```

Answer (score 1):

At the last lines you didn't assigned the vector to the attribute dLoc with the `=` operator, but 'called' it with parentheses instead, as it were a method. Put the `=` and everything should be fine.

Also, you don't need to add parentheses on the vector. The script with several corrections as follows:

```py
import bge

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner

# Constants have UPPERCASE identifiers
MAXVEL = 0.5
BRKVEL = 0.05
CRSVEL = 0.005
ACCELL = 0.001

# Sensors
w = cont.sensors['W']
s = cont.sensors['S']
a = cont.sensors['A']
d = cont.sensors['D']
space = cont.sensors['space']

# Actuators
motion = cont.actuators['motion']

## Movement

# Accelerate     
if w.positive:
    own['vel'] += ACCELL
    motion.dLoc = [own['vel'], 0.0, 0.0]
    cont.activate(motion)

if space.positive and own['vel'] > 0 :
    own['vel'] -= BRKVEL
    motion.dLoc = [own['vel'], 0.0, 0.0]
    cont.activate(motion)
```